# How to prove that if $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is of class $C^1$, then $f$ is not onto.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, derivatives, metric-spaces

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, at page 160, question 1.b, it is asked that

> If $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is of class $C^1$, show that $f$
>   does not carry $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\mathbb{R}^2$. In fact show that
>   $f(\mathbb{R})$ contains no open subset of $R^2$.

I have started with assuming that $f(\mathbb{R})$ contains an open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and by the continuity of $f$, I have argued that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$; however, after this point, I am stuck, so I would appreciate any hint or help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}F\colon&\mathbb{R}^2&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}^2\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&f(x).\end{array}$$Then $F$ is of class $C^1$. Therefore, since $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ has measure $0$, $F\bigl(\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}\bigr)$ has measure $0$ too (here, I am using the fact that functions of class $C^1$ map sets of measure $0$ into sets of measure $0$, which is lemma 18.1 in Munkres' textbook). But $F\bigl(\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}\bigr)=f(\mathbb{R})$ and a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which contains a non-empty open subset cannot have measure $0$.

Comment: Well, that was a clever trick :) Thanks a lot for the answer sir.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another approach.

For each $N\in\mathbb N$, the restriction $f_N$ of $f$ to $[-N,N]$ is Lipschitz.  Use this to show that $f_N([-N,N])$ does not contain a rectangle, hence has empty interior.  Then since $f(\mathbb R)=\cup_Nf([-N,N])$, the Baire category theorem yields the result.

Comment: Well, in that approach, there is two problems that I have no idea how to overcome.First is that how to show a set does not contain a rectangle, and second is that what is Baire category theorem :)

Comment: If it the range contains a square, divide it into smaller squares, and sum up distances from centers of squares to obtain a contradiction.  The Baire category theorem says that a complete metric space is not the union of countably many nowhere dense sets.

Comment: By Lipschitz condition, the width of each square in the image bounded by the Lipschitz constant times the distance between the pre-images, and this will be true for any opposite points in the  boundary, each of which is in the image of a $C^1$ map ... .I'm lost sir, do you have any light ?

Comment: Say the Lipschitz constant of $f_N$ is $M$, and the area of the square is $A$.  Divide it into $n^2$ smaller squares.  The centers of these squares are in the image of $f_N$, so we $n^2$ points $x_1<\ldots<x_{n^2}\in[-N,N]$ such that $\{f(x_i),\ldots,f(x_{n^2})\}$ is the set of centers of the $n^2$ squares.

Comment: Since the distance between centers is at least $\frac{A}{n}$, we have $$\frac{A}{n}(n^2-1)\leq\sum_{i=2}^{n^2-1}|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|\leq M\sum_{i=2}^{n^2-1}x_i-x_{i-1}\leq2MN.$$ But choosing $n$ sufficiently large, we obtain a contradiction.

Comment: I have done the same computations except I just considered the rectangles on the same row :) By the way, shouldn't it be $\sqrt{A} / n $ ? Because if each small rectangle has area B, $n^2 B = A$, but this implies that width of a small rectangle $\sqrt{A} / n$, hence between the centres of two small rectangles can be at least the width of a rectangle, i.e $\sqrt{A} / n$.

Comment: Yes, it should be $\sqrt A$, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, by the way. Your answer gave me a much deeper understanding about the Lipschitz contdition.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help!